# Change Size of FancyBox2 Previous and Next Overlays in iFrame?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a nice FancyBox2 implementation that loads html pages within an iFrame as a gallery.

However, the content I'm loading in the iframe includes links to external websites that are "blocked" if I use the normal previous and next navigation that allows the user to slide through all of the gallery items.

How can I change the size of the prev/next link overlay so that they are contained to the left and right margins so that I can expose the content link to the user?

OR

An alternative would be if there is a way to position the button navigation bar relative to the top of the FancyBox rather than relative to the top of the page. In this case I would disable the internal prev/next links and arrows.

Comment: I edited my answer to cover the two scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : If you want to change the size of the prev/next overlay, add this CSS inline declaration **AFTER** you loaded the fancybox CSS file :

```
<style type="text/css">
.fancybox-nav {
  top: 50%;
  height: 34px;
  width: 36px;
 }
.fancybox-nav span {
  visibility: visible;
 }
.fancybox-next span {
  left: auto;
  right: 0px;
 }
.fancybox-prev span {
  left: 0px;
 }
</style>
```

Notice that you have to make the arrows permanently visible, otherwise visitors won't know where to hover.

**NOTE**: This is for fancybox v2.0.6+

On the other hand, you cannot set the button navigation bar relative to the top of the FancyBox because it has a `position:fixed` and it's appended to the `body` tag.

However, you may try editing the fancybox-buttons js file (line 69+/-) and append it to the `.fancybox-skin` selector instead and then play with the position of the `#fancybox-buttons` selector using css.